# save time with the desired date

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

below is my html code

```
 <MKB:TimeSelector ID="TimeFrom" runat="server" DisplaySeconds="False">
                                                </MKB:TimeSelector>
```

and a text box which is having a date.

```
VehicleBookingDate.Text
```

I want to save date and time in my database. for that if I want to do like below

```
 string t1 = tsTimeFrom.Hour.ToString() + ":" + tsTimeFrom.Minute.ToString() + " " + tsTimeFrom.AmPm.ToString();

 DateTime Time_From = Convert.ToDateTime(t1);
```

It saves time with current date, where as I want to save this time with this date which is in VehicleBookingDate.Text.

how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// use a string formatter to pull it all together
string s = string.Format("{0} {1}:{2} {3}",
                         VehicleBookingDate.Text,
                         tsTimeFrom.Hour,
                         tsTimeFrom.Minute,
                         tsTimeFrom.AmPm);

// You can parse it this way, which will assume the current culture settings
DateTime Time_From = DateTime.Parse(s);

// Or you can be much more specific - which you probably should do.
DateTime Time_From = DateTime.ParseExact(s,
                                         "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You may want to use a specific culture instead if you know it.

Be aware that date formats vary significantly by culture.  For example, the value `1/4/2013` could be interpreted as either January 4th or April 1st depending on what part of the world you are in.  You either need to be culture aware, or you need to explicitly tell your user what format to use.